# How many time $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ can cross if $\int_0^\infty g(x)-f(x) dx=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty g(x)-f(x) dx=0
\end{align}
where both $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are conitinous, differentiable, positive,  monotone decreasing and  \begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)=0, \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0.
\end{align}
We also assume $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are distict, i.e, set $S=\{x: f(x)\neq g(x) \}$ has a non-zero measure.

What can we say about cardinality of 
\begin{align}
X=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)=g(x),\text{ and for some } \epsilon>0, \ [f(x−\epsilon)<g(x)<f(x+\epsilon)]∨[f(x−\epsilon)>g(x)>f(x+\epsilon)] \}
\end{align}

Basically, $X$ counts have many times  $g(x)$ and  $f(x)$ cross each other (I hope I defined it correctly).

My answer would be that $X$ is at most countable. But how to show it?

Another question. I am interested in what mild condition on $f$ or $g$ can we impose such that there are no cross after some $x_0$.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ distinct? Otherwise, the answer is "uncountably many times."

Comment: Please check your integral for missing parentheses.

Comment: I don't think $X$ counts what you want it to count.  What you're looking for is something like $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+:f(x)=g(x),\exists\varepsilon>0[f(x-\varepsilon)<g(x)<f(x+\varepsilon)]\vee[f(x-\varepsilon)>g(x)>f(x+\varepsilon)]  \}$

Comment: If $g(x) < f(x+\epsilon)$ and $g(x) > f(x-\epsilon)$ then $f(x+\epsilon) > f(x-\epsilon)$, which is impossible if $\epsilon > 0$ and $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: Certainly $X$ can be uncountable, assuming you fix things up to mend the problem @RobertIsrael noticed.

Comment: @Aweygan,  thanks correct the definition of the set.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank Fixed now.

Comment: @zhw fix the definition. Can you show me an example when $X$ is uncountable.

Comment: Still bad.  $X$ could be an interval, taking all $\epsilon = 1$.

Comment: The set needs to be redefined as $X = \left\{x \in \mathbb R^+ \mid f(x) = g(x),\, \exists\epsilon > 0 \,[ \forall c, 0<c<\epsilon, f(x-c) > g(x) > f(x+c)]\right\}$. We need the $0<c<\epsilon$ interval to all satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is that $X$ is the set of points $x$ where $f(x) = g(x)$ and there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $s,t$ with $x-\epsilon < s < x < t < x+\epsilon$, $(f(t) - g(t))(f(s) - g(s)) < 0$.  That's at most countable because all such points are isolated.

On the other hand, maybe you want the set of points $x$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $s,t$ with $x-\epsilon < s < x < t < x+\epsilon$ and $(f(t) - g(t))(f(s) - g(s)) < 0$.  That could be uncountable: in fact it could be the Cantor set.

Comment: I just want to count have many time $g$ and $f$ cross each other, but excluded "kisses"

Comment: But you need correct definitions of "cross each other" and "kisses".